# How do I get an authentication token in C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, curl

I've following CURL string to obtain a token from an URL

```
$(curl 'https://api.api.api.com/api/auth/auth/oauth/token' -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'authorization: Basic KZZZOnRoaJJms3NlQ3JluO==' --data 'grant_type=password&scope=webclient&username=user1.user2&password=???????????'| jq -r '.access_token')
```

Now, i need to obtain same result in c# (ASP.net).

I've tried with this but receive always NO AUTHORIZATION

```
 Private Sub AuthTOKEN()

    Try
        Dim consumerSecret As String = "KZZZOnRoaJJms3NlQ3JluO=="
        Dim accessToken As String
        Dim myURL As String = "https://api.api.api.com/api/auth/auth/oauth/token"

        Dim byte1 As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("grant_type=password&scope=webclient&username=user1.user2&password=password")

        Dim bearerReq As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(myURL), HttpWebRequest)
        bearerReq.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        bearerReq.Method = "POST"
        bearerReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        bearerReq.ContentLength = byte1.Length
        bearerReq.KeepAlive = False
        bearerReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(consumerSecret)))
        Dim newStream As Stream = bearerReq.GetRequestStream()
        newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length)
        Dim bearerResp As WebResponse = bearerReq.GetResponse()

        Using reader = New StreamReader(bearerResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim response = reader.ReadToEnd()
            Dim bearer As Bearer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Bearer)(response)
            accessToken = bearer.access_token
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(accessToken)
        Console.Read()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
    End Try

End Sub
```

I lost something.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like VB not c#

Comment: request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=password&scope=webclient&username=user1.user2&password=???????????")     ...try to pass request Content as stringcontent instead of byte[].

Comment: HttpWebRequest doesn't expose .Content. Where do i pass  ?

Comment: ah sorry I forgot that's from HttpClient. Have you tried consumer secret without converting into byte[] & Base64string ? try to pass like "Basic KZZZOnRoaJJms3NlQ3JluO=="

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
    Private Sub AuthTOKEN()

    Try
        Dim consumerKey As String = "Basic"
        Dim consumerSecret As String = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=="
        Dim accessToken As String
        Dim myURL As String = "https://api.api.api.com/api/oauth/token"

        Dim x As String
        x = "grant_type=password&scope=webclient&username=user1.user2&password=xxxxx"

        Dim byte1 As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x)
        Dim bearerReq As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(myURL), HttpWebRequest)
        bearerReq.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        bearerReq.Method = "POST"
        bearerReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        bearerReq.ContentLength = byte1.Length
        bearerReq.KeepAlive = False

        bearerReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & consumerSecret)
        Dim newStream As Stream = bearerReq.GetRequestStream()

        newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length)
        Dim bearerResp As WebResponse = bearerReq.GetResponse()

        Using reader = New StreamReader(bearerResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim response = reader.ReadToEnd()
            Dim bearer As Bearer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Bearer)(response)
            accessToken = bearer.access_token
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(accessToken)
        Console.Read()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks Jigar.